Linear mixed model with dependent variable range constrained by predictor
I conducted an experiment where participants rated stimuli on a visual analog scale with a range between 0 (lowest possible rating) and 100 (highest) under two viewing conditions (restricted exposure time: Gist, and long exposure: LE).
Ratings for the two viewing conditions were recorded in two separate columns, RatingGist and RatingLE, respectively, with a third column RatingDELTA ranging from -100 to +100 recording the difference in ratings between the Gist and LE viewing conditions for a given observation (RatingDELTA = RatingGist - RatingLE).
My aim is to find participant- and stimulus-level variables that predict RatingDELTAin a linear mixed effects model (fitted using R's lme4), with RatingGist as a baseline.
The problem I am facing is that all fitted models systematically underestimates high values and overestimates low values, resulting in a residual pattern (see attached plots). This might be caused by the range of RatingDELTA being dependent on the RatingGist-value for any given observation; for example, when RatingGist = 5, then RatingDELTA can only take on values between -5 (RatingLE = 0) and 95 (```RatingLE = 100).
My question is whether this can be accounted for in my model using a mathematical function or transformation to resolve the residual pattern.
Here is the model formula for reference:
lmer(RatingDELTA ~ RatingGist + Sex + zPolNum*Publisher + HChannel + VChannel + Anisotropy + Complexity + (1 + RatingGist + VChannel + Anisotropy | Interview) + (1 + PolNum | Publisher:Stimulus))



I think I would model RatingLE as the dependent variable. Since you consider RatingGist as known, you can then trivially derive RatingDELTA. I would not use a simple linear model. I would consider modelling RatingLE as a proportion (with logit link and appropriate distribution family) but there might be better approaches for this type of data.
